# AWS workspace creation fails with no error code, how can I diagnose the issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I'm trying to automate the creation of AWS workspace but i'm running into this error as output. Any idea on what could be causing the error?

```
$jsonObject = '{
  "UserNames": ["user1", "user2", "user3"],
  "DirectoryId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "BundleId": "xxxxxxxx",
  "VolumeEncryptionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled": true,
  "RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled": true,
  "WorkspaceProperties": {
    "RunningMode": "ALWAYS_ON",
    "RootVolumeSizeGib": 175,
    "UserVolumeSizeGib": 100,
    "ComputeTypeName": "PERFORMANCE"
  },
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "xxxxxxx",
      "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}'

$workspaceData = $jsonObject | ConvertFrom-Json
$failedRequests = @()

foreach ($username in $workspaceData.UserNames) {
    $workspaceProperties = @{
        "RunningMode" = $workspaceData.WorkspaceProperties.RunningMode
        "RootVolumeSizeGib" = $workspaceData.WorkspaceProperties.RootVolumeSizeGib
        "UserVolumeSizeGib" = $workspaceData.WorkspaceProperties.UserVolumeSizeGib
        "ComputeTypeName" = $workspaceData.WorkspaceProperties.ComputeTypeName
    }

    $tags = $workspaceData.Tags | ForEach-Object {
        $tag = New-Object -TypeName "Amazon.WorkSpaces.Model.Tag"
        $tag.Key = $_.Key
        $tag.Value = $_.Value
        $tag
    }

    $workspace = New-Object -TypeName "Amazon.WorkSpaces.Model.WorkspaceRequest"
    $workspace.DirectoryId = $workspaceData.DirectoryId
    $workspace.UserName = $username
    $workspace.BundleId = $workspaceData.BundleId
    $workspace.VolumeEncryptionKey = $workspaceData.VolumeEncryptionKey
    $workspace.UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled = $workspaceData.UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled
    $workspace.RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled = $workspaceData.RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled
    $workspace.WorkspaceProperties = $workspaceProperties
    $workspace.Tags = $tags
    
    try {
        New-WKSWorkspace -Workspace $workspace
    } catch {
        $failedRequests += $_.Exception.Response.FailedRequests
    }
}

$failedRequests  # Display the failed requests, if any
```

Running the script with the actual users even without the array generates the same error and there is no error code to reference
FailedRequests                                         PendingRequests

---

{Amazon.WorkSpaces.Model.FailedCreateWorkspaceRequest} {}